# Elasticsearch 6.7 _reindex operation inconsistently reports mapper errors

Tags: elasticsearch

I have written to a utility to reindex specific documents that were originally put into the wrong Elasticsearch indices. I am trying to understand what seem to be spurious -- or at least inconsistent -- reports of failures to reindex *specific* documents, even though other documents in the same batch (that should presumably fail for the same reasons) are successfully reindexed.

#### Background

My company has a system that creates a daily index of events received from devices in the field. Due to a design misunderstanding very early on, the index that a particular event was written to was determined by its *date of arrival* at our system; whereas the actual requirement was to put the event into the index corresponding to its *date of occurrence*.

For more than 99% of events, these two times yield the same date (and thus the same index). Most of the exception cases are events that occur close to UTC midnight between day N and day N+1. Also, a small handful are caused by connectivity or other failures that may cause an event to be delivered to the system arbitrarily late (days or weeks).

I've written a utility in Go to find and move these exceptional event documents to the indices they properly belong in. It uses the `github.com/olivere/elastic` package ([v6.2.26](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/tree/v6.2.26)) to interact with the Elasticsearch cluster.

Mostly this utility works great, but occasionally (and increasingly) it is stopping with a `400 Bad Request` error from the `_reindex` operation, after reindexing only a subset of the events in a batch for a particular day.

Unfortunately the `elastic` package [doesn't return the response body](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/v6.2.26/reindex.go#L320-L348) when it returns an error from `ReindexService.Do`, so I've had to adapt the code from [this article](https://medium.com/@clasikas/golang-and-elasticsearch-how-to-get-raw-request-body-json-and-a-little-more-9ee345a9149b), which intercepts and logs the response body down in the HTTP client, to see the details.

#### The Issue

Below are some log lines (manually reformatted for readability) associated with a typical occurrence of this error. `message_id` is a 64-bit nanosecond-resolution Unix epoch encoded as a hexadecimal string, which represents the time-of-occurrence of an event.

In this particular case, two event documents out of a batch of twelve are not reindexed because of a mapping violation (can't change the type of a field):

```
findEventTime  event_time="2019-05-19 13:45:52.562001331 +0000 UTC" 
               event_ts=15a0198a3b5815b3
               message_id=15a0198a3b5815b3

event time     event_time="2019-05-19T13:45:52.562001331Z"
               events_date=2019-05-19
               source_index=event-store-2019-06-25
...
ES request     method=POST
               req_body="{\"dest\":{
                             \"index\":\"event-store-2019-05-19\",
                             \"op_type\":\"create\",
                             \"version_type\":\"external\"
                         },\"source\":{
                             \"index\":\"event-store-2019-06-25\",
                             \"query\":{
                                 \"range\":{
                                     \"message_id\":{
                                         \"from\":\"159fec78e07d0000\",
                                         \"include_lower\":true,
                                         \"include_upper\":false,
                                         \"to\":\"15a03b0d71cc0000\"}}}}}"
               url="http://events.es.yoyodyne.com/_reindex"

ES response    rsp_body="{\"took\":183,
                          \"timed_out\":false,
                          \"total\":12,
                          \"updated\":0,
                          \"created\":10,
                          \"deleted\":0,
                          \"batches\":1,
                          \"version_conflicts\":0,
                          \"noops\":0,
                          \"retries\":{\"bulk\":0,\"search\":0},
                          \"throttled_millis\":0,
                          \"requests_per_second\":-1.0,
                          \"throttled_until_millis\":0,
                          \"failures\":[
                              {\"index\":\"event-store-2019-05-19\",
                               \"type\":\"_doc\",
                               \"id\":\"5eadba4f-dd1f-4141-8fdb-4dc9e363b9ff\",
                               \"cause\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",
                                          \"reason\":\"mapper [params.severity_metrics.torque.value] cannot be changed from type [long] to [float]\"},
                               \"status\":400},
                              {\"index\":\"event-store-2019-05-19\",
                               \"type\":\"_doc\",
                               \"id\":\"8070134f-5f2b-4cbe-85a7-c4636c1f529f\",
                               \"cause\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",
                                          \"reason\":\"mapper [params.severity_metrics.torque.value] cannot be changed from type [long] to [float]\"},
                               \"status\":400}]}"
               status=400
```

Now, it is true that these two events do have `params.severity_metrics.torque.value`s that are dotted decimals, so *superficially* the reported errors might seem reasonable:

```
$ ./esq.sh -q -I event-store-2019-06-25 -c params.severity_metrics.torque -e id 8070134f-5f2b-4cbe-85a7-c4636c1f529f | jq '.hits.hits[] | ._source.params.severity_metrics'
{
  "torque": {
    "severity": "med",
    "value": 3.9
  }
}
$ ./esq.sh -q -I event-store-2019-06-25 -c params.severity_metrics.torque -e id 5eadba4f-dd1f-4141-8fdb-4dc9e363b9ff | jq '.hits.hits[] | ._source.params.severity_metrics'
{
  "torque": {
    "severity": "med",
    "value": 4.4
  }
}
```

#### However...

**1.** Of the ten documents that *were* successfully indexed by this `_reindex` operation, five of them **also** have `params.severity_metrics.torque.value`s that are dotted decimals (the other five having the value `0`):

```
$./esq.sh -q -I event-store-2019-06-25 -z 12 -c id -c params.severity_metrics.torque \
          -r message_id gte 159fec78e07d0000 lt 15a03b0d71cc0000 | jq -c '.hits.hits[] | {id: ._source.id, severity_metrics: ._source.params.severity_metrics}'
{"id":"5eadba4f-dd1f-4141-8fdb-4dc9e363b9ff","severity_metrics":{"torque":{"severity":"med","value":4.4}}}
{"id":"d9274787-58c8-46bf-93ad-dd9d0d3d854a","severity_metrics":{"torque":{"severity":"high","value":29.5}}}
{"id":"1b5a2072-8b88-4a90-a12b-91db171f6210","severity_metrics":{"torque":{"severity":"none","value":0}}}
{"id":"a8e20619-d4c6-44f2-8e9a-16826e933892","severity_metrics":{"torque":{"severity":"high","value":13.3}}}
{"id":"96e951fe-2841-4d69-b7d6-36c31201ff3d","severity_metrics":{"torque":{"severity":"high","value":31.3}}}
{"id":"d63141d5-1714-4caa-9542-5860c0eb0881","severity_metrics":{"torque":{"severity":"none","value":0}}}
{"id":"432fecec-762f-4a66-81ef-3071b3544e70","severity_metrics":{"torque":{"severity":"med","value":3.5}}}
{"id":"85eb8492-7e4f-4441-b747-d5333b322992","severity_metrics":{"torque":{"severity":"high","value":381.4}}}
{"id":"8070134f-5f2b-4cbe-85a7-c4636c1f529f","severity_metrics":{"torque":{"severity":"med","value":3.9}}}
{"id":"398dee7e-4160-4697-9a2e-41e1c00c7381","severity_metrics":{"torque":{"severity":"none","value":0}}}
{"id":"5304ef1f-1160-4ed4-9423-f9cf672f7ddf","severity_metrics":{"torque":{"severity":"none","value":0}}}
{"id":"11fadf45-71d4-4d7a-b92e-9f1515ead36f","severity_metrics":{"torque":{"severity":"none","value":0}}}

$ ./esq.sh -q -I event-store-2019-05-19 -z 12 -c id -c params.severity_metrics.torque \
  -s -e id d9274787-58c8-46bf-93ad-dd9d0d3d854a \
     -e id a8e20619-d4c6-44f2-8e9a-16826e933892 \
     -e id 96e951fe-2841-4d69-b7d6-36c31201ff3d \
     -e id 432fecec-762f-4a66-81ef-3071b3544e70 \
     -e id 85eb8492-7e4f-4441-b747-d5333b322992 | jq -c '.hits.hits[] | {id: ._source.id, severity_metrics: ._source.params.severity_metrics}'
{"id":"d9274787-58c8-46bf-93ad-dd9d0d3d854a","severity_metrics":{"torque":{"severity":"high","value":29.5}}}
{"id":"a8e20619-d4c6-44f2-8e9a-16826e933892","severity_metrics":{"torque":{"severity":"high","value":13.3}}}
{"id":"96e951fe-2841-4d69-b7d6-36c31201ff3d","severity_metrics":{"torque":{"severity":"high","value":31.3}}}
{"id":"432fecec-762f-4a66-81ef-3071b3544e70","severity_metrics":{"torque":{"severity":"med","value":3.5}}}
{"id":"85eb8492-7e4f-4441-b747-d5333b322992","severity_metrics":{"torque":{"severity":"high","value":381.4}}}
```

So why did the `_reindex` operation reindex (and not complain about) those five documents?

**2.** Both the source and the destination indices' mappings agree that the field in question is a `long`:

```
$ curl -s $ESHOST/event-store-2019-06-25/_mapping | jq '.["event-store-2019-06-25"] | .mappings._doc.properties.params.properties.severity_metrics.properties.torque'
{
  "properties": {
    "severity": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "value": {
      "type": "long"
    }
  }
}
$ curl -s $ESHOST/event-store-2019-05-19/_mapping | jq '.["event-store-2019-05-19"] | .mappings._doc.properties.params.properties.severity_metrics.properties.torque'
{
  "properties": {
    "severity": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "value": {
      "type": "long"
    }
  }
}
```

This of course raises the question: "How could those documents that have `params.severity_metrics.torque.value` as a decimal have existed in the source index `event-store-2019-06-25` in the first place?"

**3.** If I manually delete from the source index those ten documents that were successfully reindexed, and then re-run my utility, the `_reindex` operation happily accepts the two documents that it rejected on the prior run, and adds them to the target index without complaint. WTF?

**So:** *How is all this possible?* What am I not understanding about mappings or the `_reindex` operation that would reasonably explain all these (seemingly contradictory) symptoms I am seeing?

---

BTW, if you are wondering, `esq.sh` is a local script I use to simplify the composition of Elasticsearch queries. Options used above are:

```
-I <index-name>
-c <source-field>
-e <name> <val>                        (equality)
-r <name> <op> <val> [<op> <valu>...]  (range)
-q                                     (quiet; suppress echo of formatted request body)
-s                                     (should; roughly logical-OR)
-z <num>                               (size)
```

---

#### Update: A few things are a bit clearer now...

Big shout out to [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64078623/1337498) for opening my eyes to a few things:

First, apart from specifying that `params` is an `object`, and -- via a mapping template -- that any `params.*` whose value is a string is stored/indexed as a `keyword`, the mapping spec for these indices says *nothing* about how to store/index `params.*` values having other types.

```
{
  "mappings":{                                                                                                                                                                                            
    "_doc":{                                                                                                                                                                                                
      "properties":{
        ...
        "params":{                                                                                                                                                                                           
          "type":"object"                                                                                                                                                                                     
        },
        ...
      },
      "dynamic_templates":[                                                                                                                                                                                 
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                    
          "Keyword Params":{                                                                                                                                                                                  
            "mapping":{                                                                                                                                                                                        
              "type":"keyword"                                                                                                                                                                                  
            },                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            "match_mapping_type":"string",                                                                                                                                                                     
            "path_match":"params.*"                                                                                                                                                                            
        },
        ...
      ]
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  }
}
```

(This makes a certain amount of sense, since our events are derived from 20-odd different message types; and while there is some commonality of parameters across message types, there is also a lot of diversity.I'm not 100% certain, but I think that our applications *don't* generally do aggregations, or even queries, of numeric message-parameter values, so for the moment I'm disinclined to mess with the existing mapping definitions. I'm guessing that the original designer didn't care much how numeric parameter values would be represented in the index, but only really cared that string-typed parameter values not get analyzed.)

Obviously this (non-)decision about the types of numeric params means that Elasticsearch chooses the type of the field in a particular index, based on the first value it sees for that field coming into that index. And because of the way JSON marshals numbers (omitting the fractional part if it is zero), if an integral value (typically 0) is the first value of that parameter to arrive at the index, by default the parameter will be a `long`, and otherwise it will be a `float`.

This also clarified for me the idea that the representation of the value in the JSON document source is somewhat independent of the mapped value that Elasticsearch indexes/stores. It's perfectly reasonable (if a bit confusing) to see *source* values like `4.4` and `3.9` for a field that stores those values as `4` and `3`. This is (I assume) why original documents, being indexed for the first time, don't elicit any complaints from Elasticsearch, even if the manifest representation of a parameter value like `4.4` can't be fully accommodated by the receiving index's type mapping for that field.

In the reindexing case, I can also see how Elasticsearch would (or, at any rate, *might*) flag an error if the mapped type of the field in the source index differed from the mapped type of the field in the destination index. (This of course assumes that the `_reindex` operation carries that source-index type information along as it tries to reindex into the destination, rather than just indexing the original JSON source document.)

So, some aspects of the situation are a bit clearer now. But I am still failing to understand why such errors occur:

- for some documents in a batch, but not for others that would appear to have the same issue,
- when both the source and destination indices agree on the type of the field

and why they *don't* occur on a retry for the very same documents.

---

#### Update 2: Into the Java rabbit hole

I did a bit more searching for the reported error ("mapper cannot be changed from type") and found [this article](https://medium.com/@federicopanini/elasticsearch-6-0-removal-of-mapping-types-526a67ff772) that contains a link to the function (`MappedFieldType.checkTypeName`) that produces that error message ([link for Elasticsearch 6.7](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/6.7/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/mapper/MappedFieldType.java#L141)).

So *something, somewhere* in Elasticsearch thinks that the `params.severity_metrics.torque.value` field of a particular incoming document should be `float`, even though for other documents coming in the same batch, it has been established that it's a `long`.

This got me to thinking about what might be happening in different shards, which led me to this (2014) Elasticsearch issue [#8688](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8688) ("Mapping updates should be synchronous").

That issue was fixed, but it still seems possible that what I'm seeing might be a result of that fix. That is, if there's a conflict, only one of the two mappings can win, and those that lose end up in the response body's `failures` array.

This may or may not be the case, but it doesn't seem to be specifically *shard*-related, since one of the two failed documents from my example (with the value `4.4`) routes to the same shard (0) as a different document (with the value `29.5`) that *succeeded* on the initial `_reindex` request.

```
$ curl -s events.es.yoyodyne.com/event-store-2019-05-19/_search?pretty -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "explain": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "term": { "id": "8070134f-5f2b-4cbe-85a7-c4636c1f529f" } }, <=== failed
        { "term": { "id": "5eadba4f-dd1f-4141-8fdb-4dc9e363b9ff" } }, <=== failed
        { "term": { "id": "d9274787-58c8-46bf-93ad-dd9d0d3d854a" } },
        { "term": { "id": "a8e20619-d4c6-44f2-8e9a-16826e933892" } },
        { "term": { "id": "96e951fe-2841-4d69-b7d6-36c31201ff3d" } },
        { "term": { "id": "432fecec-762f-4a66-81ef-3071b3544e70" } },
        { "term": { "id": "85eb8492-7e4f-4441-b747-d5333b322992" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}' | jq -c '.hits.hits[] | [._id, ._shard, ._source.params.severity_metrics.torque.value]'
["432fecec-762f-4a66-81ef-3071b3544e70","[event-store-2019-05-19][2]",3.5]
["85eb8492-7e4f-4441-b747-d5333b322992","[event-store-2019-05-19][2]",381.4]
["d9274787-58c8-46bf-93ad-dd9d0d3d854a","[event-store-2019-05-19][0]",29.5] <=== succeeded (shard 0)
["5eadba4f-dd1f-4141-8fdb-4dc9e363b9ff","[event-store-2019-05-19][0]",4.4]  <=== failed (shard 0)
["8070134f-5f2b-4cbe-85a7-c4636c1f529f","[event-store-2019-05-19][3]",3.9]  <=== failed (shard 3)
["a8e20619-d4c6-44f2-8e9a-16826e933892","[event-store-2019-05-19][1]",13.3]
["96e951fe-2841-4d69-b7d6-36c31201ff3d","[event-store-2019-05-19][1]",31.3]
```

I've cloned the Elasticsearch repo, but of course it'a a monster, and I have no grounding whatsoever in how requests flow through Elasticsearch; plus I only look at Java code about once a year (if I'm lucky!). So I'm doubtful that I will be able to devote the necessary time to tracking this down in the source code.

Maybe someone with knowledge of Elasticsearch internals could help out here?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to replicate this (tested w/ `7.2.0`).

What could alleviate this, though, is setting [`coerce: true`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html#number-params) in the `long` mapping.

---

Now, it may be a matter of (reasonable) legacy decisions but `long` for such values does not seem to make sense. You've got decimal values such as `4.4` and `3.9` and I presume you'll want to do some math on them. Under the current mapping even the simplest of numeric aggs, the sum,

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "my_sum": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "severity_metrics.torque.value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

would end up stripping the decimal parts (coercing to a `long`) and giving you a result of `7`.

So I'd recommend a `double` (not even a `float` -- try yourself and see why). Let's then see if this seemingly inexplicable issue reoccurs.

Comment: Thanks for these observations. They got me to look a bit deeper at the mappings defined for these indices, and to understand some subtleties that I hadn't fully appreciated before (see my update in the OP). Upvoting for usefulness, but holding off on accepting, since the observed behavior is still a mystery, and I'm disinclined to mess with the existing mappings, at least for now.

Comment: Added another update, FWIW. I think I'm getting warmer, but I'm doubtful that I'll be able to find the treasure myself.

Comment: that makes two of us when we talk (or rather not wanna talk) about Java internals  I reckon that after all your investigative work this appears to be a perfect candidate for a new GH issue.